# How to create a GtkPixbuf from a stock item llike (new_from_stock)?

Tags: gtk

I want to get a stock item to use it in a treeview but I can't get it as a pixbuf directly as there is no `new_from_stock` method for pixbufs!!

Comment: Actually stock items has been deprecated now with Gtk+-3.10. You should not use to write new code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

say you want to get a pixbuf from `stock_item`.

There are 2 ways:

First (easy):

```
pixbuf = gtk_widget_render_icon ( widget, stock_item, size )
```

Second (hard):

You need to look for it in the list of default icon factories:

```
icon_set = gtk_style_lookup_icon_set ( style, stock_item )
```

OR:

```
icon_set = gtk_icon_factory_lookup_default ( $stock_item )
```

then check available sizes with `get_sizes`.
Check if the size you want is available or get the largest size which will be the last in the returned list.
Then you need to render it to get the pixbuf:

```
pixbuf = gtk_icon_set_render_icon ( icon_set, style, direction, state, size, widget )
```

Then scale it to whatever size you want using:

```
gdk_pixbuf_scale_simple ( pixbuf, width, height, GdkInterpType )
```

Hope you got it

Comment: One comment to this (correct) answer: `GtkIconSet` will be deprecated in 3.10. I believe the future-proof way to do the same is by using  `gtk_icon_theme_load_icon()/gtk_icon_theme_load_icon_for_scale()` but I have never actually used them myself.

Answer (score 2):

Are you aware of the icon-name property in GtkCellRendererPixbuf? That should solve the problem of showing a stock icon in a treeview.

Comment: won't work if I want to use a pixbuf from a file in another row

Answer (score 0):

A slightly easier (and more future-proof) version of ophidion's answer is to do the following:

```
#define ICON_NAME "go-next"
#define ICON_SIZE 96 /* pixels */

GError *error = NULL;

GtkIconTheme *icon_theme = gtk_icon_theme_get_default();
GdkPixbuf *pixbuf = gtk_icon_theme_load_icon(icon_theme, ICON_NAME, ICON_SIZE,
                                             GTK_ICON_LOOKUP_USE_BUILTIN, &error);
```

Assuming you don't get an error, you can then put the resulting `GdkPixbuf` in a treemodel, or use it with a `GtkButton`, or whatever else you'd like to do with it.

As others have pointed out, [GTK stock items are likely to be deprecated](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1KCVPoYQBqMbDP11tHPpjW6uaEHrvLUmcDPqKAppCY8o/pub), so you should use names according to the [Icon Naming Spec](http://standards.freedesktop.org/icon-naming-spec/icon-naming-spec-latest.html#names) instead if you want to be future proof. See [this Google Docs spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/pub?key=0AsPAM3pPwxagdGF4THNMMUpjUW5xMXZfdUNzMXhEa2c&output=html) for the equivalent icon spec names for GTK stock items.

Answer (score -1):

You can use [`gtk_image_new_from_stock()`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkImage.html#gtk-image-new-from-stock), then get the raw pixbuf using [`gtk_image_get_pixbuf()`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkImage.html#gtk-image-get-pixbuf).

But check out [@jku's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18403365/28169) answer first, that sounds like the proper solution. I just wanted to add how you'd do it in any other context.

Comment: Tried that but it didn't work because storage type of image is neither `GTK_IMAGE_PIXBUF` nor `GTK_IMAGE_EMPTY`.